# running multiple instances of tomcat on Centos

Tags: tomcat

On Centos 6.4, I am trying to run multiple instances of tomcat based on this tutorial:
[http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188102/](http://web.archive.org/web/20141004194803/http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188102/)

in order to illustrate the problem, I copy the default configuration to a new instance `/srv/tomcat/solr` keeping the same default port values (and I stop the default service /etc/init.d/tomcat6 to avoid port conflicts), as follows:

```
sudo su -

yum install tomcat6

name=solr

mkdir -p /srv/tomcat/${name}/logs
mkdir /srv/tomcat/${name}/webapps
mkdir /srv/tomcat/${name}/work
mkdir /srv/tomcat/${name}/temp
cp -R /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/ /srv/tomcat/${name}
#rm /srv/tomcat/${name}/conf/tomcat6.conf  # this line is not in the tutorial, but adding it produces the same result
chown -R tomcat. /srv/tomcat/

ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat6 /etc/init.d/${name}

cat >/etc/sysconfig/${name} <<EOF
CATALINA_BASE="/srv/tomcat/${name}"
CATALINA_PID="/var/run/${name}.pid"
CONNECTOR_PORT="8080"
TOMCAT_LOG="/srv/tomcat/${name}/logs/catalina.out"
EOF

# I keep the default port values at: /srv/tomcat/solr/conf/server.xml

/etc/init.d/tomcat6 stop   # to avoid port conflicts
/etc/init.d/${name} start  # i start my new instance

[root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/${name} start
Starting solr:                                             [  OK  ]

[root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/${name} status
PID file exists, but process is not running                [FAILED]

[root@localhost ~]# cat /srv/tomcat/solr/logs/catalina.out 
/usr/sbin/tomcat6: line 30: /srv/tomcat/solr/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied
```

what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/sysconfig/${name}, remove the following line

```
TOMCAT_LOG="/srv/tomcat/${name}/logs/catalina.out"
```

it's the default path (anyway) and it's causing your error